# PHP not displaying error and not inserting any after adding validation

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that inserts into a database but after trying to add some validation it no longer works. It does not echo the error from the validation and it does not insert into the database. I am trying to validate that the user provided 'make' and that the 'year' and 'mileage' are numeric. If it does not pass validation display error message on page. If validation passes insert into database. It was inserting into db before adding the validation. Thank you.

PHP

```
$failure = false;
$success = false;

if ( isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage'])) {

    if (strlen($_POST['make']) < 1) {
        $failure = "Make is required";
    } else {
        if ( (is_numeric($_POST['mileage']) !== true) || (is_numeric($_POST['year']) !== true) ) {
            $failure = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make, year, mileage)
                      VALUES (:make, :year, :mileage)";
            //echo("<pre>\n".$sql."\n</pre>\n");
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':make' => $_POST['make'],
                ':year' => $_POST['year'],
                ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage']));

            $success = "Record inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Tracking Autos for <?php echo($_GET['name']); ?></h1>
<?php
if ( $failure !== false ) {
    echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($failure)."</p>\n");
}
if ( $success !== false ) {
    echo('<p style="color: green;">'.htmlentities($success)."</p>\n");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<p>Make:
<input type="text" name="make" size="60"/></p>
<p>Year:
<input type="text" name="year"/></p>
<p>Mileage:
<input type="text" name="mileage"/></p>
<input type="button" value="Add">
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>
```

Comment: Is your php and html code in the same file ?

Comment: Yes. The file has a .php extension.

Comment: Do some debugging. Write some text inside every "if" and "else" block to see how execution works. Find out what exactly is not working as expected.

Comment: Should your "Add" button also be submit? Print_r whole $_POST array to see if values are passed when you click "Add" button.

Comment: Which button are you clicking on to submit the form? You need to use the `Logout` button. The `Add` button doesn't do anything unless you have a JavaScript event listener attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Add" button is not in "submit" type so it won't submit the form and pass field values by making post request. Change button type to "submit".